# Which Oracle Java EE tutorial I Should use? Java EE 6 Tutorial or Java EE 5 Tutorial?

Tags: jakarta-ee

I'm a newbie with Java EE technology. I did take a Java programming course at uni (introductory and intermediate level).

I want to start with the oracle Java EE tutorials but I'm not sure which one I should use (Java EE 6 Tutorial or Java EE 5 Tutorial)?

Comment: Go with the latest one.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely go with the Java EE 6 tutorial. Java EE 6 is more than 3 years old now and fully established.

In fact, in only 2 months Java EE 7 will come out. If you're doing this purely for self study you could even consider going straight to Java EE 7. There are lots of resources available for that already and the official tutorial will be released [at the same time](https://blogs.oracle.com/theaquarium/entry/last_java_ee_6_tutorial) that Java EE 7 will be released.

Answer (score 0):

Depends of what you want to do with it (immediate industry application or just personnal skill improvments ?) Java EE 6 is a bit young for now and not totally adopted by industry, anyway it's really simpler and more powerful than the 5th release (am Java EE 5 architect certified). 
Web part (JSF) is also particulary more mature and user friendly in the last version.
I would advice to start with a web profile and have a deep look into CDI features which is the main innovation in the Java EE 6 Stack.

Enjoy